# Create dynamic parent child relationship

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, data-mining

I have a user and group database. There are a lot of groups on the database and each group has a lot of member. For example;

- User1 is member of Group1, Group2, Group3
- User2 is member of Group2
- User3 is member of Group2, Group5

There is a parent-child relationship among the groups. Parent groups are more general groups. For example,

- Group2: Programmers
- Group5: .NET Programmers

On the database, there is no parent-child relationship among the groups. How can create dynamic parent-child relationship? I there any algorithm about these problem?

Thanks for reply.

Comment: It's not clear to me what exactly are you looking for, can you try to clarify that? Do you want to be able to use the “dynamic relationship” in SQL queries? Also, why don't you just modify the database?

Comment: "There is a parent-child relationship among the groups" "On the database, there is no parent-child relationship among the groups" How can it be, if the DB is all you have now?

Comment: Which group is the parent group is unknown. We must define the parent groups dynamically. For example,user#1 member of asp.net, web development and IT groups, user#2 member of php, web development and IT groups, user#3 member of asp.net, php and web development groups etc. There are billions of records. Whe can automaticallly determine that web development group is parent group of ASP.NET ve PHP. Is there any data mining algorithm to determine the parent groups?

Comment: It's not clear why you need dynamic relationship. If .NET Programmers is a subgroup of Programmers, that is always the case. Why should it sometimes not be the case? Also, what is the criteria to determine whether group1 is a subgroup of group2? Is it subset relation?

Comment: I want to determine the relationships using data mining. There are thousands of groups and grows rapidly. I want to set parent-child relationships dinamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through every item, filling table child1Parent2[groups,groups]. At start it is full of trues. For every group check condition: g1 is set and g2 is not set. If it is true, set false to chuld1Parent2[gr1,gr2]. At the end of iteration you have the table wich contains all parent-child info.

```
boolean child1Parent2[groups,groups];
for( g1:groups) for(g2:groups) {
    child1Parent2[g1,g2]=true;
}
for (itemRow:rows){
    for( g1:groups) for(g2:groups)
        if (child1Parent2[g1,g2])
        if (itemRow.contains(g1)& !itemRow.contains(g2))
            child1Parent2[g1,g2]=false;
}
```

As a result you have: `child1Parent2[g1,g2] === (g1 is a child of g2)`

A piece of advice for future: if you want to find some info, think about how this info will be declared, what structure could it have. You'll understand much more on the subject.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your answer.

Comment: I edited the answer - have chewed everything. Sorry, you must swallow yourself. If you don't understand some place, ask for that place. My English is far from ideal, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an adjacency list for groups and parent groups yon need to store it in the database. There isn't a way to find it dynammically without having it stored somewhere. You can use a roulette wheel if the precision is good enough.

Comment: We need a clustering algoritm. Web programmers group is a cluster, and PHP, ASP.NET member of the cluster.

Comment: @hanzala: Sure, but why do you need a cluster algorithm? Usually a cluster algorithm is used in discrete math to simplify the dimensional complexity. For example you can use a quadkey to solve problems like tiling, bounding box, closest-pair of points etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can run an association rule mining process, and consider association rules to be parent-child relationships, when they are frequent enough.

I.e. when you find out that a membership in group A implies with 99% support a membership in group B, then B is a supergroup of A.

Note that you don't even need a full APRIORI, with it's tricks to save recomputations and prune results. Essentially, you can just compute the conditional likelihoods right away (when the minimum support is enough), and keep those that satisfy your thresholds.